# StreamWriter and StreamReader Not Working Properly

Tags: c#, wpf, streamreader

I have been trying to understand for hours now why my project (full desktop app) won't let me use StreamWriter or StreamReader in a proper manner. The issue is that if I try to give either the StreamWriter or StreamReader a filePath (just a simple string) as shown below ...

```
private readonly string _filePath = @"...Text.txt";

public string TestMethod(string text)
{    
        // Does not accept a string as an argument, which it should based on the documentation
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader();
        text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();

        return text;
}
```

Edit: Running the above code trying to make all the red lines go away will case the error posted further down this post.

Below is what it currently looks like (wrong)

[image: Wrong]

[image: Correct]

Above is what it should look like (correct - with a path paramter)

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.110).aspx

... I get errors all over the place and if I try to do it another way giving it other arguments I get an error saying:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Console, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

I tried to create a whole new solution, which consists of 2 class libraries (so 2 projects for 1 solution, I guess would be correct to say?) and it pretty much works. I did this because my other solution consists of 3 class libraries, so I thought it would be a good idea to be consistent in reproducing the problem, if I could. So, I created a simple text file, populated it with some text, and got it as output on the screen in a TextBox in the new solution. This basically left me with no idea what to do now.

Does anybody know what might cause this issue?

Comment: What kind of project is this, is it a full desktop app or is this a app store app or a phone app?

Comment: Please post your code and error messages as text, not as screenshots. That said, you mention "a filePath (just a simple string)" -- can you give examples of the kind of complexity in the string that you fear would contribute to problems with StreamReader?

Comment: What .net framework is your project targeting? Look at the project properties.

Comment: My guess is your target framework might not support this overload. Did you try `File.ReadAllText("path")`

Comment: Alright, I tried to update the post as you guys requested - all projects target .NET Stanard 1.4 - and yes I have indeed tried `File.ReadAllText("path")` . It causes the same error.

Comment: I just checked the test solution I created. The target framework there is .NET Framework 4.6.1 :O

Comment: This may a dumb question, but you declare a variable called `reader` then try to use one called `writer` which isn't declared. Is that what's going on?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Haha.. sorry, as I was writing the code, I modified it and forgot to change it when I pasted it in here. I corrected it. Thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, the `StreamReader` class in the version of .Net that you are targeting (.Net Standard 1.4) does not support a constructor that takes a file path.

You would need to use the `FileStream` class to open the file and then use the `StreamReader` to read the file.

Below is an example copied from the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netstandard-1.4

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test 
{

    public static void Main() 
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";

        try 
        {
            if (File.Exists(path)) 
            {
                File.Delete(path);
            }

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path)) 
            {
                sw.WriteLine("This");
                sw.WriteLine("is some text");
                sw.WriteLine("to test");
                sw.WriteLine("Reading");
            }

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) 
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs)) 
                {

                    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, the `StreamReader` in your current .NET does not have the appropriate overload that can take file path. You can use other alternative approaches. You can use `FileStream` for opening the file you want and then use `StreamReader` for reading.